# How to import empty strings as null values from CSV file - using pgloader?

Tags: postgresql, csv, pgloader

I am using **pgloader** to import from a .csv file which has empty strings in double quotes. A sample line is

> 12334,0,"MAIL","CA","","Sanfransisco","TX","","",""

After a successful import, the fields that has double quotes ("") are shown as two single quotes('') in postgres database.

Is there a way we can insert a null or even empty string in place of two single quotes('')?

I am using the arguments -

```
WITH truncate,
           fields optionally enclosed by '"',
           fields escaped by double-quote,
           fields terminated by ','
SET client_encoding to 'UTF-8',
           work_mem to '12MB',
           standard_conforming_strings to 'on'
```

I tried using 'empty-string-to-null' mentioned in the documentation like this -

```
CAST column enumerate.fax using empty-string-to-null
```

But it gives me an error saying -

> pgloader nph_opr_addr.test.load An unhandled error condition has been
>   signalled: At LOAD CSV
>
> ^ (Line 1, Column 0, Position 0) Could not parse subexpression ";"
>   when parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the field option:

```
null if blanks
```

Something like this:

```
...
having fields foo, bar, mynullcol null if blanks, baz
```

From the [documentation](http://pgloader.io/howto/pgloader.1.html):

> *null if*
>
> This option takes an argument which is either the keyword blanks or a double-quoted string.
>
> When blanks is used and the field value that is read contains only space characters, then it's automatically converted to an SQL NULL value.
>
> When a double-quoted string is used and that string is read as the field value, then the field value is automatically converted to an SQL NULL value

Comment: Thanks that was what I needed. dimitri also gave a details explanation at https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/334